# Use return value as argument to method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Is it possible to use the return value of a method as the argument for a different method invocation?  I'm using Objective-C.

What I'm going for is something like this:

```
stringOutput = [object1 method1:[object2 method2:[object3 method3]]];
```

where method 3 returns a string that goes into method 2, which returns a string that goes into method 1, which returns a string that goes into stringOutput.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me; it seems like you're not meaning 'argument' in a standard sort of way.  Can you explain some more?

Comment: Short answer, no. An argument by definition, does not have arguments. You can chain methods though - something like [obj method: [myargissuppliedby anotherMethodArg]];

Comment: I believe I meant parameter, not argument. I edited above.

Comment: Are you referring to a feature available in a different language? If so, what is it?

Comment: @Deepak: No, not that I'm sure of. Basically I want to do this:

stringOutput = [class method:[class method:[class method]]];

Comment: You should be able to do nested method calls. Nick's example does a single level nesting. You can apply that to two levels just as you want.

Comment: The nomenclature here is still bad. I'll edit it to make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean sending the result from one method as the parameter for another?

```
NSString *string = [self myMethod:[self myMethod2]];
```

Where the methods are

```
- (NSString *)myMethod2 {
    return @"A String";
}

- (NSString *)myMethod:(NSString *)string {
    // Do something with string

    // Return another string
    return @"Something else";
}
```

Comment: This! Parameter was the word I was looking for, not argument. But could you embed that again? As in -(NSString *)myMethod:[NSString(myMethod2):NSString(myMethodOfMyMethod2)]

Comment: You're not making much sense - what is the syntax you're aiming for in this comment?

Comment: @James - The words "parameter" and "argument" are synonymous in this context.

Comment: @James, @Sherm - "parameter" and "argument" are never synonymous.  Methods have parameters; when invoking a method, the caller must provide an argument for each parameter of that method.  Nick's answer is correct - it's a fundamental part of the language.  You're doing it all the time already probably - `[[MyClass alloc] init]` is probably the most common example.